# How to return a class from a property get

Tags: c#

I have this simple class property which should return a MyGuest class based on Guest. When I run the code using debugger in step mode, execution is looping betwen line 5 and 6.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
1.    public Guest MyGuest
2.    {
3.        get
4.        {
5.            MyGuest = new Guest();
6.            return MyGuest;
7.        }
8.       set { }
9.    }
```

Comment: I got a working solution when I converted the VB to C# code using http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp.

This is the working code.

   // Guest - returns an Guest object...
    public Guest MyGuest
    {
        get
        {
            Guest functionReturnValue = default(MyGuest);
            functionReturnValue = new Guest();
            functionReturnValue.Configure(this);
            return functionReturnValue;
        }
        set { }
    }

Answer (score 2):

Its a recursive loop because line 6 is calling 3 to get the value again.  You want:

```
public Guest MyGuest { get { return new Guest(); } }
```

But do you really want to return a new `Guest` when the method is called?